# Which aircraft can fly at FL600 or above?

Tags: aircraft-performance, high-altitude

I would like to know some examples of aircraft (specific models) which can fly at FL600 or higher.

I am interested in aircraft which can or could fly at that altitude on a regular basis (service ceiling included). Space exploration or launcher systems are out of the scope.

As far as I know, commercial airplanes cannot fly that high so I can only think of jet fighters, aerostatic balloons, and rocket-powered aircraft.

Comment: Are you interested in one-offs and limited-production aircraft such as White Knight Two?

Comment: @Mark I am interested in aircraft which often fly (or have flown) in that altitude range. But any other "experimental airborne system" is welcome as well.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- **Commercial Airliners:**

  Both [Concorde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorde#Specifications) (service ceiling FL600) and the [Tupolev Tu-144](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-144#Specifications_(Tu-144D)) (service ceiling FL660) could reach FL600. Most airliners have a service ceiling of around FL410 though.
- **Business Jets:**

  According to [this article](https://www.aerospace-technology.com/features/featurethe-sky-is-not-the-limit-the-highest-altitude-passenger-planes-4186188/) the highest service ceiling for various business jets is at FL510, so none can reach FL600.
- **Military Reconnaissance Aircraft:**

  The [Lockheed SR-71 Blackbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird#Specifications_(SR-71A)) had a service ceiling of FL850 and routinely operated above FL600. Many other aircraft in this category (e.g. [MiG-25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikoyan-Gurevich_MiG-25#Specifications_(MiG-25P)), [Tsybin RSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsybin_RSR), [U-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2#Specifications_(U-2S)), [RB-57F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin/General_Dynamics_RB-57F_Canberra#Specifications), [M-17 and M-55](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myasishchev_M-55)) can also fly above FL600.
- **Military Fighter Jets:**

  Most fighter jets have a service ceiling below FL600, but there are a few that can fly higher (e.g. [F-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-15_Eagle#Specifications_(F-15C)) and [F-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-22_Raptor#Specifications_(F-22A)) with service ceilings of FL650, the [MiG-25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikoyan-Gurevich_MiG-25#Specifications_(MiG-25P)) again, and  [MiG-31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikoyan_MiG-31) with the highest service ceiling of FL820+ for a fighter).
- **Experimental Aircraft:**

  Wikipedia has a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_altitude_record) of altitude records, often by experimental craft. The 60,000 feet limit was surpassed around the end of the second world war with the advent of rocket and turbojet engines. Two notable achievements:

  The rocket powered [X-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_X-15) reached space twice. In 1963 it climbed to 67 miles, nominally corresponding to FL3530. Note that the X-15 did not self-start.

  The glider (!) [Perlan II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windward_Performance_Perlan_II) has a service ceiling of FL900 and actually reached 76,124 feet. It utilizes standing waves forming at mountain ranges which under certain conditions can extend into the stratosphere. From [wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlan_Project) "A sailplane at 90,000 feet altitude flies in approximately the same aerodynamic regime [...] to be experienced by a moderate size aircraft flying near the surface of Mars."

High altitude balloons and rockets can of course fly higher.

Comment: As I recall, the U-2 (in the Reconnaissance class) also operated above FL600, though I don't remember its service ceiling (which was limited by "coffin corner", where Mach limit of the airframe intersects stall speed).

Comment: James May goes to 70000 feet in this vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-COlil4tos but at that altitude there is still 40kts margin above stall and they are still climbing and bleeding speed, so the U2 could make it to at least 75000.

Comment: There's also the [RB-57F Canberra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin/General_Dynamics_RB-57F_Canberra). I think NASA still has a few flying.

Comment: @FredLarson they do.  One of NASAs WB-57's was used to record infrared video of the Crew Dragon In Flight Abort test earlier this week.

Comment: Not saying you're wrong, but I expected to see the MiG-25 in the "fighter jet" section.  Interesting to learn it was considered a "Reconnaissance Aircraft".

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yes, it kind of belongs to both categories...

Comment: I took the liberty of editing in M-17 & M-55. Punched them under the reconnaisance category, M-55 is basically a research aircraft, but I bet that it's not solely used for scientific purposes ;)

Comment: ... and added MiG-31 as the highest flying fighter jet, service ceiling is reported to be 82000ft

Comment: @Jpe61 Thanks! I turned this into a community wiki post now since several users contributed already. This should make it easier for others to make additions...

Comment: @ZeissIkon According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2#Specifications_(U-2S)) ceiling is FL800.

Comment: Sorry for messing with the indentation. Apparently the editor in iOS app can’t cope with formatting too well, or I can’t find the right buttons. Could someone fix, please?

Comment: While Tsybin RSR was designed to have a high ceiling, it never made it past initial testing - all actual flights were done on a simplified flying lab with reduced performance (it never flew higher than 4000m, for example). The finished aircraft never flew, so I don't think it belongs on this list...

Comment: @JPhi1618 the reconnaiscance versions of the MiG-25 could fly higher than the fighter versions, not sure how much higher. They're probably lighter because they lack the wing pylons for the very large missiles carried on the fighter.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov and if it does, so do several very similar US and UK designs from the same period

Comment: Since the OP asked for rocket planes -- X15 qualifies. Perhaps other experimental aircraft? Unmanned?

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the definition of Service Ceiling the [English Electric Lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Electric_Lightning) just squeaks into the military fighter list.  For early variants, if the climb profile was carefully managed, it could operate for about 90 seconds at FL600 before the airspeed bled off to the stall point.

Comment: While interesting, I don’t see how this answers the question as asked by the OP.

Comment: @dalearn The OP asked *I am interested in aircraft which can or could fly at that altitude on a regular basis.*  if the Lightning could do it, even if only for a short period, why isn't it a valid answer to the question?

Comment: @Graham the poster says that it depends upon the definition of Service Ceiling, but It seems like the EE Lightning had a negative rate of climb at FL600, which would mean it is not an answer.

Comment: Maybe not, but English Electric certainly belongs on the list, thanks to the original Canberra (leading to the RB-57)

Comment: There's a difference between "flying at FL600" and "reaching FL600 in a zoom climb".