# Mathematical relation between thrust and propeller motor at 20km altitude

Tags: aircraft-performance

20km from earth surface
key factors to consider pressure, density and temperature.
I am using continuity equation but i don't know how to find the value of velocity ,power.

Comment: Are you sure you're asking the right question? This question https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73647/which-aircraft-can-fly-at-fl600-or-above has no examples of prop-driven aircraft capable of operating at that height. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_altitude_record) lists only two prop-driven aircraft capable of reaching that altitude. One is uncrewed, and both are specialised high-altitude research aircraft.